# How to persist nested pojo objects in Java?

Tags: java, database, couchdb, persist, nosql

I have class Rowdata

```
public class FileData {
    Map<Long, List<String>> cacheData = new LinkedHashMap<Long, List<String>>();
    List<String> header = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Map<Long, List<String>> getCacheData() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(cacheData);
    }

    public List<String> getHeaderMapping() throws Exception {
        return header;
    }
    public void putData(long key, List<String> row) {
        cacheData.put(key, row);
    }
    public int size() {
        return cacheData.size();
    }
    public void setHeader(List<String> header) {
        this.header = header;
    }


}
```

I would like persist this object. What is the best way to persist? Shall I proceed with RDBMS? then what is the table schema?

Or Shall I proceed with NoSQL? then We already have CouchDB in our project . Please advice on this.

Comment: There is so many ways you could persist it, there is no way to determine which is best.  How about you make the class Serializable and write it to a file for example? If you have CouchDB, why not use the code already written as a example of how to persist it?

Comment: @PeterLawrey We are running our application in cluster mode. So serialization wont help us. Since I am our aware in CouchDB so I prefer any RDBMS solution.

Comment: In that case, do what you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: Any solution in RDBMS